# Dropdown menu open on hover instead of click on shopify

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

I'm trying to edit a shopify theme and the last part I'm stuck on is getting these navigation menus to open on hovering instead of clicking.  The css I have for the menus is:

```
.site-nav {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 0;

  a {
    padding: 3px 10px;
  }

  li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

.site-nav--centered {
  padding-bottom: $gutter-site-mobile;
}

/*================ Site Nav Links ================*/
.site-nav__link {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;

  .site-nav--centered & {
    padding-top: 0;
  }

  .icon-chevron-down {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    margin-left: 2px;

    .site-nav--active-dropdown & {
      transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
    }
  }

  &.site-nav--active-dropdown {
    border: 1px solid $color-border;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}

/*================ Dropdowns ================*/
.site-nav--has-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.site-nav--has-centered-dropdown {
  position: static;
}

.site-nav__dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: $dropdown-padding;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: $z-index-dropdown;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid $color-border;
  background: $color-bg;
  left: -1px;
  top: 41px;

  .site-nav__link {
    padding: 4px 30px 4px 0;
  }

  .site-nav--active-dropdown & {
    display: block;
  }

  li {
    display: block;
  }
}

// Centered dropdown
.site-nav__dropdown--centered {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The HTML and Liquid for the header is:

```
      {% if section.settings.align_logo == 'left' %}
        <nav class="grid__item medium-up--one-half small--hide" id="AccessibleNav" role="navigation">
          {% include 'site-nav' %}
        </nav>
      {% endif %}
```

And the relevant menu Javascript:

```
/* ================ MODULES ================ */
window.theme = window.theme || {};

theme.Header = (function() {
  var selectors = {
    body: 'body',
    navigation: '#AccessibleNav',
    siteNavHasDropdown: '.site-nav--has-dropdown',
    siteNavChildLinks: '.site-nav__child-link',
    siteNavActiveDropdown: '.site-nav--active-dropdown',
    siteNavLinkMain: '.site-nav__link--main',
    siteNavChildLink: '.site-nav__link--last'
  };

  var config = {
    activeClass: 'site-nav--active-dropdown',
    childLinkClass: 'site-nav__child-link'
  };

  var cache = {};

  function init() {
    cacheSelectors();

    cache.$parents.on('click.siteNav', function(evt) {
      var $el = $(this);

      if (!$el.hasClass(config.activeClass)) {
        // force stop the click from happening
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
      }

      showDropdown($el);
    });

    // check when we're leaving a dropdown and close the active dropdown
    $(selectors.siteNavChildLink).on('focusout.siteNav', function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        if ($(document.activeElement).hasClass(config.childLinkClass) || !cache.$activeDropdown.length) {
          return;
        }

        hideDropdown(cache.$activeDropdown);
      });
    });

    // close dropdowns when on top level nav
    cache.$topLevel.on('focus.siteNav', function() {
      if (cache.$activeDropdown.length) {
        hideDropdown(cache.$activeDropdown);
      }
    });

    cache.$subMenuLinks.on('click.siteNav', function(evt) {
      // Prevent click on body from firing instead of link
      evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
  }

  function cacheSelectors() {
    cache = {
      $nav: $(selectors.navigation),
      $topLevel: $(selectors.siteNavLinkMain),
      $parents: $(selectors.navigation).find(selectors.siteNavHasDropdown),
      $subMenuLinks: $(selectors.siteNavChildLinks),
      $activeDropdown: $(selectors.siteNavActiveDropdown)
    };
  }

  function showDropdown($el) {
    $el.addClass(config.activeClass);

    // close open dropdowns
    if (cache.$activeDropdown.length) {
      hideDropdown(cache.$activeDropdown);
    }

    cache.$activeDropdown = $el;

    // set expanded on open dropdown
    $el.find(selectors.siteNavLinkMain).attr('aria-expanded', 'true');

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(window).on('keyup.siteNav', function(evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode === 27) {
          hideDropdown($el);
        }
      });

      $(selectors.body).on('click.siteNav', function() {
        hideDropdown($el);
      });
    }, 250);
  }

  function hideDropdown($el) {
    // remove aria on open dropdown
    $el.find(selectors.siteNavLinkMain).attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    $el.removeClass(config.activeClass);

    // reset active dropdown
    cache.$activeDropdown = $(selectors.siteNavActiveDropdown);

    $(selectors.body).off('click.siteNav');
    $(window).off('keyup.siteNav');
  }

  function unload() {
    $(window).off('.siteNav');
    cache.$parents.off('.siteNav');
    cache.$subMenuLinks.off('.siteNav');
    cache.$topLevel.off('.siteNav');
    $(selectors.siteNavChildLink).off('.siteNav');
    $(selectors.body).off('.siteNav');
  }

  return {
    init: init,
    unload: unload
  };
})();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I feel so silly asking a simple question like this.  I just can't figure out where to put `:hover` in the code. It seems pretty strait forward but I can't get it.  You can see the site here: AlexandIvy.myShopify.com and the password to view it is staysk.  I'm just talking about the top navigation menus.

This is the code from the console:

```
<nav class="grid__item medium-up--one-half small--hide" id="AccessibleNav" role="navigation">
          <ul class="site-nav list--inline " id="SiteNav">


      <li class="site-nav--has-dropdown">
        <a href="/collections/bedding" class="site-nav__link site-nav__link--main" aria-has-popup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="SiteNavLabel-bedding">
          Bedding
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon icon--wide icon-chevron-down" viewBox="0 0 498.98 284.49"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#231f20}</style></defs><path class="cls-1" d="M80.93 271.76A35 35 0 0 1 140.68 247l189.74 189.75L520.16 247a35 35 0 1 1 49.5 49.5L355.17 511a35 35 0 0 1-49.5 0L91.18 296.5a34.89 34.89 0 0 1-10.25-24.74z" transform="translate(-80.93 -236.76)"></path></svg>
          <span class="visually-hidden">expand</span>
        </a>

        <div class="site-nav__dropdown" id="SiteNavLabel-bedding">
          <ul>

              <li>
                <a href="/collections/sheet-sets" class="site-nav__link site-nav__child-link">Sheet Sets</a>
              </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Comment: Post all of the relevant code needed to reproduce the current nav please.

Comment: You may consider NOT doing this when you consider anyone on mobile. Hover is not a concept you can do on a mobile device. You REQUIRE a touch to open a dropdown menu and then a second touch to navigate to your destination.

Comment: A verifiable demo with rendered code please. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How would I go about converting it?  And I just added the html for the header part of the page.  I can't find a reference to the site-nav in it though.  I can't imagine it'd be in another file.

Comment: I posted the javascript too. I didn't realize that was part of it at first.

Comment: The theme was made for a click/tap, hover doesn't exist on touch devices. Some touch devices will open with a tap, Android will not open the menu on tap, it will go to the link. You may also have trouble with hybrid devices.

Comment: @Christina  So, if I were to use hover or mouseover the menu wouldn't work on Android phones at all?  This could be what I needed to convince the person I'm doing it for that it's a horrible idea and we should give up on it.

Comment: @JennyHolder - not without swapping the menu js and the css to work with the latest Superfish (https://github.com/joeldbirch/superfish), which does work on both IOS and Android. The thing would be to apply their CSS to your classes (you don't have to use their styles) and remove all of the other menu js and use that instead.

Comment: Click/tap menus are the now, hover is the past. Google, Facebook, Twitter, Bootstrap, all click menus which just work on touch and desktop. So it is a horrible idea to swap out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using JS to hide/show the dropdowns, I suggest you do this if you're comfortable with JQuery.

```
$('.site-nav--has-dropdown').hover(function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass('activated')){
    $(this).removeClass('activated');
    $(this).children('.site-nav__dropdown').css('display', 'none');
  }
  else{
    $(this).addClass('activated');
    $(this).children('.site-nav__dropdown').css('display', 'block');
  }  
});
```

The idea behind this is that the child closest to `.site-nav--has-dropdown` which has a class name `.site-nav__dropdown` can be activated on hover. You can use *pol's* code too which provides a different (and shorter) approach.

Comment: I haven't done  much JQuery so I'm not sure what I would have to replace with your code.  The html from the console for the menu is in the question now.

Comment: @JennyHolder You just have to add this code inside `<script></script>` tags

Comment: It looks like that is partially working, the only problem is the menus don't disappear once the mouse is moved off.  You should be able to see it in action here: https://alexandivy.myshopify.com/collections/sheet-sets   password is staysk

Comment: @hulkinBrain  I actually tried that myself a few minutes ago.  It's still having the same issue with it not disappearing.

Comment: @JennyHolder Sorry, i fell asleep, i wasn't able to answer it earlier. I've updated the code now. It'll surely work now.

Comment: It's still having issues, the menu disappears once you try to click on it.

Comment: @JennyHolder i have updated the code, this time it'll work, i tried it on your website at my end.

Comment: I ended up using your script and had to change the CSS a bit too.  Just the margins for some reason...  Thank you so much for the help! You have no idea how relieving this is :-)

Comment: @JennyHolder happy to help :D, did you use my updated code?

Comment: Yep! It's perfect now  XD  Happy Friday!

Comment: @JennyHolder Hahaha! Cheers! xD

Answer (score 1):

You should use `mouseover`/`mouseout` methods in jquery.

```
$('.site-nav--has-dropdown').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).children('.site-nav__dropdown').show();
});

$('.site-nav--has-dropdown').mouseout(function() {
  $(this).children('.site-nav__dropdown').hide();
});
```

---

Or just use css `:hover`,
to better support touch devices you should add `:focus` too.

```
.site-nav--has-dropdown:hover .site-nav__dropdown,
.site-nav--has-dropdown:focus .site-nav__dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

jsfiddle demo: [sfiddle.net/8p33qh9h](https://jsfiddle.net/8p33qh9h/)